# Upvoting a long unseen question

Tags: discussion, voting

I have been stumbling across questions recently that are very similar to problems I have had but were asked a year or two ago.

Is the right thing to do to upvote the question as something I too have had a problem with? If the answer works I should upvote that too, right?

Comment: If the question/answer is good upvote it, the age shouldn't factor into the equation at all

Comment: There is no voting rule. Do as you like.

Comment: I more mean is this the right thing to do if I come across a question I was about to post

Comment: Why do you think the age of a question/answer is relevant for your voting behavior if you considered it useful or interesting?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure, You should upvote them if they met the basic criteria

- Show research effort
- **Useful** (Like in your case)
- Clear

If you hover your mouse over upvote question button, you will see the helpful guide.

So if a question is useful to you, then you should upvote it **no matter when it was posted.**

Answer (score 17):

As always, how you vote is entirely up to you (apart from voting fraud), as such do what you feel is best.

If you're asking what **I** think you should do; if the question/answer is good upvote it, the age shouldn't factor into the equation at all. The fact they helped you suggests they probably are useful and worthy of an upvote.

Answer (score 10):

You should vote on questions regardless of their age.  If you find the posts useful, upvote them; if you find them to be not useful, downvote them.  If you do not have an opinion, abstain from voting.

Some questions/answers may be less useful as time goes on, some will be just as useful, others more useful.  Evaluate each question on its own merits.

Answer (score 2):

I would upvote them, if they are useful for me. But as already said - it's up to you.

Let me give you an example: [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery)
It's not the best question on stackoverflow, but it's something that's useful for many many users and that's why it got so many upvotes.